# DDD referencing large data sets / injecting repository?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am struggling to find the best solution to the following. I need to determine whether a Country is "InUse", (e.g. currently referenced by an Address).

I have the following simplified model mapped in NHibernate:

```
class Address
{
  public Country Country {get; set;}
}

class Country
{
  public List<Address> Addresses {get; set;}

  bool IsInUse()
  {
    return Addresses.Any();
  }
}
```

Using the IsInUse method on Country is inefficient, as it would result in a load of all countries (the .Any() is executed in memory). In addition, Country doesn't really need to know about Addresses, it's purely there for the IsInUse method. So, I like the above example from a consumer point of view, it feels like the domain object should expose an IsInUse method, but it will not perform and contains unnecessary relationships.

Other options I can think of are;

1. Just use a repository and call that directly from service layer. The repository could encapsulate a call that simply issued a SELECT COUNT(*), rather than SELECT *, as would be the case with the lazy load option above. This options leave the IsInUse logic entirely outside of the domain layer.
2. Inject a repository into IsInUse(), which calls out to the same as above. I have read that this is VERY bad DDD practise.

Does anyone have any advice or better solutions to this problem.

Hope the above makes sense... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you not calculate it each time you perform the query.  Denormalize the `IsInUse`.  Each time an address is added or removed from a country you can determine whether the country is in use and save that value.

How you go about determining that value is another story and there are various techniques ranging from immediately determining it when you save the address and updating the country's `IsInUse` value or even using messaging if these happen to be entities in different BCs.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you're making up domain concepts to solve your issue. Could you tell us why you need to know if a country is in use?

Repositories are great for capturing the language and aggregate persistence, not so much for querying. You're basically asking your data a question. Maybe move this logic altogether to the query side? Also see http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/01/repositories-where-did-we-go-wrong_26.html.

Maybe there is another way to keep track of all the countries in use. Where are those addresses coming from? Maybe you can introduce domain events - *when* an address is registered, add the country to the list of countries in use, so you can query a smaller list.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. In principle I need to know whether the object is in use so that I can determine whether it can be edited or deleted (the country example is not my real code, I used country for simplicity, but in principle assume country cannot be changed if it is in use). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd design your domain entities without concepts from NHibernate or any other persistence mechanism.  If this means that by using NHibernate you need to introduce 2-way mapping properties as standard, then I would only use your NHibernate entities within your repositories and design a separate set of entities for your domain model and map between the two.  It's seems plausible to me, from your business's point of view, that a `Country` shouldn't know anything about `Address`.

Injecting the repository into your domain entity or using lazy loading typically go against DDD and cause issues when you serialize your entities or they lose database context.

Your `IsInUse` problem can be solved by either caching a query (not everything religiously has to be in a repository), maybe you could create a `CountryStatistics` class that handles this?  Or you could keep a separate persisted country list, which gets updated every time a new address is created with a never-used-before country.